# My computer boots to a black screen without press Tab? what can I do to fix it?

Tags: boot, grub2

My ubuntu is 18.04, and if I boot my computer with the press of the **Tab**(*It just show the purple screen, then display the login screen*) and it will boot normally. 
But if without press the **Tab**(*This time it just black, and nothing else*), my computer will always be a black screen.
I can't figure out what problem is it. Can someone help me?
If you need some more other information, Please let me know?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to specify _when_ you press Tab and what happens. Is it displaying the GRUB menu, for example? Do you then keep the default option in GRUB? Adding some screenshots could help. What’s your hardware specification? (I guess it might be related to graphics.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
When your computer starts press 
`ESC key` and it'll take you to the system setup settings with BIOS and everything.
Then select System Recovery ,in mine I had to press `F11` for System Recovery it might be different in yours.
You'll then be directed to the Ubuntu advanced settings screen where you can run Ubuntu in recovery mode .
After you run it in recovery , select

```
Update or remove broken dpkg in grub
```

Then you'll be get a screen with multiple options select the first option that is install new software and press y for everything.